# res.json express not working

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm trying to run a simple response.json() with express but it doesn't make the json itself.

The node.js file: server/app.js

```
"use strict";

let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../client"));

app.get('/sports', function(request, response) {
  response.json( ["Cycling", "Weightlifting"] );
});

app.listen(8181, () => console.log("Listening on 8181"));
```

The terminal runing the server:

```
$ node app.js 
Listening on 8181
```

The "test" for the response.json():

```
$ curl -i localhost:8181/sports
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 19
Date: Fri, 10 Jun 2016 20:23:17 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Cannot GET /sports
```

I really don't know what is going on because this is an example of a video in codeschool and is a copy of this git commit and everything looks the same :( https://github.com/codeschool/OlympicsMEAN/commit/767c89b8b0025861cefac910f98d79ef52cb3497

Thanks

Comment: This has *nothing to do with JSON*, the API evidently isn't running

Comment: I just tested your code, it works, you might be killing you app before the curl

Comment: is there any package that I may be forgetting ?

Comment: Are you restarting the server after changing `app.js`?

Comment: yes, I'm restarting the server

Comment: I found it :) thanks a lot